Powershell Merge items Array of Objects without duplicates
I have an array with object and some objects have a duplicate property values:
#Try to Sort
$Array=@()

$Array += [pscustomobject] @{
        'Num' = 100
        'text' = "Hello"
    } 
$Array += [pscustomobject] @{
        'Num' = 100
        'text' = "Hello world"
    } 
$Array += [pscustomobject] @{
        'Num' = 120
        'text' = "Goodby"
    } 
$Array += [pscustomobject] @{
        'Num' = 120
        'text' = "EveryOne"
    } 
$Array += [pscustomobject] @{
        'Num' = 110
        'text' = "Hans"
    } 



$Array| Sort-Object -Property Num

In the End there should an array looks like that:
Num text       
--- ----         
100 Hello world  
110 Hans 
120 Goodby EveryOne

How can I check no duplicate text and no duplicate Num, but lost no information?

Why is "Hello" + "Hello world" = "Hello world", but "Goodby" + "Everyone" = "Goodby Everyone"? What's the merging logic?

The Solution should include no duplicates. So "Hello" is in "Hello world", so it shouldn't be mentioned.

Group items by Num property, then for each group of objects, split each text property value on empty space and get unique items (what the HashSet[string] is for) and lastly join the unique items back.
$hash = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
    [System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)

$Array | Group-Object Num | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Num  = $_.Name
        text = (-split $_.Group.text).Where{ $hash.Add($_) } -join ' '
    }

    $hash.Clear()
}


Here are my Solution:
write-host "-----"
$duplicates = $Array.Num | Group-Object | Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } | ForEach-Object { $_.Name } 
$duplicates
foreach($dupl in $duplicates){
    $Anw=""
    $nAnw=""
    $dArr=($Array|?{$_.Num -eq $dupl}| sort { $_.Anweisung.length } -Descending)
    foreach($Case in $dArr){
    $Anw += $Case.text
    }
    $Anw
    $Anw.Split("`n")| select -Unique|foreach{$nAnw+=$_ }
    $nAnw

}

